Fast way of running coroutines from 'sync' code using uvloop
I am looking for a performant way of running coroutines from synchronous code, eg. from my own cython code. I tried calling asyncio.create_task, but it is pretty slow, perhaps because of creating a complex Task pyobject? Is there any better way, perhaps uvloop-specific?
What I tried:

I know about the possibility of calling my_coro.send(None) in a loop as a workaround, but that would imho just block the event loop until my_coro is finished. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917634/4547852)
I tried to use asyncio.queue for passing data between synchronous function and coroutine, but the overhead was also significant. Now I am considering some std::vector of futures that might be faster.

